# How to show that a vector space is closed?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am trying to complete a proof which requires me to prove that a subspace $H$ of $L^2{(\Omega,\mathcal{F}},\mathbb{P})$ is closed vector space in $L^2{(\Omega,\mathcal{F}},\mathbb{P})$

What do I need to show in order to prove this?

Comment: Depends on how this subspace is defined, maybe its image under a continuous map is closed? For example, if it's a level set/pre-image under a continuous map.

Comment: Alternatively, take any arbitrary converging sequence of $H$, and show its limit is still in $H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are focused on the *closedness* of $H$ rather than the *subspace* part, so I'll address just the closedness. (Note that if you've already established $H$ is a subspace, then $H$ is necessarily a vector space itself.)

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $H$ (Cauchy with respect to whatever norm you have on $H$). Then $x_n\to x$ for some $x$. Show that $x\in H$.

Comment: Thank you. It is a vector space by the way H has been defined. this is the space ,$H:=\{X \in L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F_{\infty}^B},\mathbb{P}) \mid X=a + \int_0^{\infty} \phi_s dB_s ,\phi \in \Lambda^2\}$ so I can easily apply Ito's Isometry here $

Comment: now that I tried to prove it, I am not so sure. I let $(x)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a cauchy sequence in $H$ s.th $\|x_n-x_m\|_2 < \epsilon$. Now since $ (x)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is also a cauchy sequence in the hilbert space $L^2$, it converges to an element $x \in L^2 $. In order to complete the proof I need to show that $x \in H$ i.e $x$ has the form $x=a+ \int_0^{\infty} \phi_s dB_s$ How could I do that? I thought I had it all figured out , till I started writing the proof.